# Fill Textbox when Radio button is selected - Visual Studio - Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I am creating an app with various radio buttons. When one of the radio buttons is selected, I would like to get a value to be automatically entered into textbox (amount).

How this can be done?

Thank you,
Kamil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have a radiobutton with the value on radiobutton text in your UI, add the [event CheckedChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.checkedchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) to your radio buttons.

```
private void RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (RadioButton1.Checked) //If checked == true
    {
        textBox1.Text = "12";
        //example
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works, however the 'text' is what I use as a label next to radio button and it uses this when running the app. What I want is to have number 12 for one radio button and number 24 for the other. Thank you

Comment: Then just do `textBox1.Text = "12";` and do it manually like this for every rediobutton

Answer (score 1):

Attach `CheckedChanged` event to radiobuttons with method that does soemthing like that
`textBox.Text = (sender as RadioButton).Text;`
With this you need only one method for all events.